# how to remove data binding in the angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new to the world of angularjs, and its fun to learn the new approach of building web applications in angular. today i got stuck while building or gnerating  on the fly.

here is the code what i have written.

```
<select>
 <option  ng-repeat="selectoption in options"   value="{{selectoption.type}}" ng-selected="selectoption.optValue === {{parent.Status}}">{{selectoption.type}}</option>
</select>
```

here is the json i created to populate the "option" tag in controller

```
$scope.options = [

                            {type:"OPEN",optValue:"open"},
                            {type:"IN PROGRESS",optValue:"inprogress"},
                            {type:"CLOSE",optValue:"close"}
                    ];
```

Said that, "select" tag will be sitting in "tr" tag with ng repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="myActivities in myAct.someObject"><td></td></tr>
```

Issue what i am finding is, every time ng-repeat inserts a new row to table "selectoption.optValue" will get binded to the value in row generated. Can anyone help me to remove this binding ?

Comment: What do you mean every time ?  it binds with your "options list" on scope and if list changes it will add or remove rows on your table.

Comment: hi Erkan.. thanks for your comment.. 

im doing 'ng-selected="selectoption.optValue == condition' where 'optvalue' will be compared by a value sitting in parent node of json. As the binding happens 'selectoption.optValue' is getting the value of last itarated element and compares with it (which is not as expected).

Comment: If you do two nested repeats, what do expect? It's basic in programming that nested loops multiplies the number of elements!

Comment: i am fine with elements getting multiplied.. what i was looking for is, i dont want the value of last element to be applied to all..

Comment: looks like i found the fix..i changed the below code <option  ng-repeat="selectoption in options"   value="{{selectoption.type}}" ng-selected="selectoption.optValue === {{parent.Status}}">{{selectoption.type}}</option> to <option  ng-repeat="selectoption in options"   value="{{selectoption.type}}" ng-selected="selectoption.optValue === '{{parent.Status}}'">{{selectoption.type}}</option>. Wrapped {{parent.Status}} in ''.

Comment: just for future reference angular.copy() creates copies of objects which means that the returned object is a new one without the data binding